# Why is there a $u$ in the middle of the feynman diagram for a quark and an antiquark annihilating?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, quarks

There is a feynman diagram in chapter 2 of Griffiths Introduction to elementary particles, where a pair annihilation is taking place. I am confused as before it was written that internal lines are virtual particles then why write $u$ stating that it has to be a quark which is we know is a real particle. Even in electron-electron scattering there was $e$ in the middle line.

[image]

Comment: in fact, virtual particles are called by the name of the particle because they carry all the quantum numbers that characterize the particle , except that their mass is off shell, within the limits of the variables of the integration implied by the diagram. Also remember that the oposing vector in the diagrams denotes an antiparticle, so in this diagram the quantum numbers of the particle meet the antiparticle and become zero, and the energy/momentum  is conserved by two real (on shell) photons,

Answer (score 2):

Any type of particle can be "real" or "virtual" in a Feynman diagram.  The difference between these is that the four-momentum of a "real" particle satisfies $p_\mu p^\mu = m^2$, while the four-momentum of a "virtual" particle does not necessarily have $p_\mu p^\mu = m^2$.